# Unable to access array within an array from Salesforce flow http callout (beta)

Tags: arrays, json, salesforce, http-get

In sandbox, I am attempting to gather the information from https://data.nasdaq.com/api/v3/datasets/USTREASURY/YIELD.json

I used the beta feature of creating an HTTP callout right from the flow. It creates an external service based on the sample response you provide.

My problem is that within the JSON created, there is an array within an array; because the response is like

```
"data":[["2023-02-02","4.62","4.65","4.66","4.76","4.64","4.09","3.75","3.49","3.44","3.4","3.67","3.55"]],
```

When I access the response from the callout within the flow, the array column_names is available, but not the array data.

The JSON created is:

```
{"openapi":"3.0.1",
 "info":{"title":"dataNasdaqGetRates"
         ,"description":""},
 "paths":{"":{"get":{"description":"",
                     "operationId":"getRates",
                     "parameters":[{"name":"api_key","in":"query","required":true,"allowEmptyValue":false,
                                    "schema":{"type":"string"}},
                                   {"name":"order","in":"query","required":true,"allowEmptyValue":false,
                                    "schema":{"type":"string"}},
                                   {"name":"limit","in":"query","required":true,"allowEmptyValue":false,
                                     "schema":{"type":"integer","format":"int32"}}],
                     "responses":{"2XX":{"description":"",
                                         "content":{"application/json":{"schema":{"type":"object",
                                                                                  "properties":{"dataset":{"type":"object",
                                                                                                           "properties":{"end_date":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "data":{"type":"array",
                                                                                                                                 "items":{"type":"array",
                                                                                                                                          "items":{"type":"string"}}},
                                                                                                                         "description":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "newest_available_date":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "type":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "dataset_code":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "column_index":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "frequency":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "oldest_available_date":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "transform":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "premium":{"type":"boolean"},
                                                                                                                         "refreshed_at":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "database_id":{"type":"integer",
                                                                                                                                        "format":"int64"},
                                                                                                                         "database_code":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "name":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "limit":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},
                                                                                                                         "id":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},
                                                                                                                         "column_names":{"type":"array",
                                                                                                                                         "items":{"type":"string"}},
                                                                                                                         "collapse":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "start_date":{"type":"string"},
                                                                                                                         "order":{"type":"string"}
                                                                                                                        }}}}}}}}}}}}
```

I've attempted to tweak the JSON to remove the nested array, hoping it might just work. I've attempted to add additional "type": to the nested array (technically the first item is a string and the rest are integers).

I was expecting there to be another apex-defined list called "data" listed after columnx5fnames; or even just a text collection or anything at all that I could add to a variable and access.
[response items menu from flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6NQ0.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an APEX defined collection variable and then assign the output from your HTTP Callout action using an Assignment element.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new collection variable. Allow Multiple Values = true, Data Type = Apex Defined:

[image: New APEX Defined Collection Variable]

2. Choose the APEX class that was created from your HTTP Callout Action and ends with the name of your array (you may have many depending on the hierarchy of your schema). In my case it is "userReports":

[image: Choose APEX Class]

3. Assign the output from your HTTP Callout Action to the new variable you created:

[image: Assign Output of HTTP Callout nested array to variable]